# how to get the server certificate with okhttp response

Tags: java, okhttp

I want to save a server certificate, but I cannot find the method to get it with `OkHttpClient`. The response.handshake is empty:

```java
client.newCall(request).execute().handshake().peerCertificates()
```

Comment: Do you mean "you have some self signed certs in truststore and you are want to view their content /  list them?"

Comment: i request to a https web site，and i want to see the certificate detail info and save it to database

Answer (score 2):

You have the correct code.  But likely you have disabled security or similar such that there is no clean certificate chain for your request.

Correct secure code

https://github.com/cashapp/certifikit/blob/master/certifikit-cli/src/main/kotlin/app/cash/certifikit/cli/http.kt#L124-L128

```
  return response.use {
    it.handshake!!.peerCertificates
  }.map { it as X509Certificate }
```

Insecure code

```
import okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall
import okhttp3.tls.HandshakeCertificates
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket

fun main() {
  val handshakeCertificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
    .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
    .addInsecureHost("self-signed.badssl.com")
    .build()

  val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(handshakeCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), handshakeCertificates.trustManager)
    .eventListener(object : EventListener() {
      override fun connectionAcquired(call: Call, connection: Connection) {
        val socket = (call as RealCall).connection?.socket() as? SSLSocket

        println("connectionAcquired " + socket?.session?.peerCertificates?.size)
        socket?.session?.peerCertificates?.forEach {
          val x509 = it as X509Certificate
          println(x509.subjectDN)
        }
      }
    })
    .build()

  val response = client.newCall(Request.Builder().url("https://self-signed.badssl.com").build()).execute()
  println("response " + response.handshake?.peerCertificates?.size)
  response.handshake?.peerCertificates?.forEach {
    val x509 = it as X509Certificate
    println(x509.subjectDN)
  }
}
```

Output

```
connectionAcquired 1
CN=*.badssl.com, O=BadSSL, L=San Francisco, ST=California, C=US
response 0
```

Comment: ```.addPlatformTrustedCertificates()``` helped me on something I've been working on for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The certifikit CLI can download them for you in an OkHttp friendly format.

https://github.com/cashapp/certifikit/tree/master/certifikit-cli

```
$  certifikit-cli git:(master) ./cft --host badssl.com --insecure --output tmp 
CN:     *.badssl.com
Pin:    sha256/f522e496c72fccc623f1ffb9da5a79cdefe16340851f22d23d0cd2a58608066f
SAN:    *.badssl.com, badssl.com
Key Usage: DigitalSignature, KeyEncipherment
Ext Key Usage: serverAuth, clientAuth
Authority Info Access:
    ocsp: http://ocsp.digicert.com
    caIssuers: http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt
Valid:  2020-03-23T00:00:00Z..2022-05-17T12:00:00Z (1 years)
CA: false

CN:     DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
Pin:    sha256/e6426f344330d0a8eb080bbb7976391d976fc824b5dc16c0d15246d5148ff75c
SAN:    <N/A>
Key Usage: DigitalSignature, KeyCertSign, CRLSign
Authority Info Access:
    ocsp: http://ocsp.digicert.com
Valid:  2013-03-08T12:00:00Z..2023-03-08T12:00:00Z (2 years)
CA: true Max Intermediate: 0

CN:     DigiCert Global Root CA (signed by locally-trusted root)
Pin:    sha256/aff988906dde12955d9bebbf928fdcc31cce328d5b9384f21c8941ca26e20391
SAN:    <N/A>
OU:     www.digicert.com
Key Usage: DigitalSignature, KeyCertSign, CRLSign
Valid:  2006-11-10T00:00:00Z..2031-11-10T00:00:00Z (11 years)
CA: true
$  certifikit-cli git:(master) ✗ ls tmp
aff988906dde12955d9bebbf928fdcc31cce328d5b9384f21c8941ca26e20391.pem  f522e496c72fccc623f1ffb9da5a79cdefe16340851f22d23d0cd2a58608066f.pem
e6426f344330d0a8eb080bbb7976391d976fc824b5dc16c0d15246d5148ff75c.pem
```